How to Implement a Global Filter in Laravel That Persists Across Multiple Views?
I am building a laravel application to aid in reviewing my trades and I want to implement a global filtering bar that maintains its state across multiple pages.
For example, if I filter for trades in October on the /trades page and then navigate to the /reports page, I want the filter to still apply and show only October trades.
What is the best and most efficient way of doing this in Laravel?

you could use user session to store backend or local storage/session storage in frontend

if you are using inertiajs for your frontend you can cache component props: https://inertiajs.com/remembering-state
